# Is it possible to restrict the policies that a developer can create?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am developing a policy for developers. I know that I can limit developers to passing only an approved list of existing policies to EC2 instances with the `iam:PassRole` action.

However, I would like developers to be able to create policies, mostly to grant limited, necessary access to the applications they are developing. I do not want to require that they hand off creation of these policies to a trusted systems team or administrator group, etc.

But if developers can create arbitrary policies, and pass arbitrary policies to EC2 instances, there's nothing to prevent them from passing an "allow all" policy to an EC2 instance they lanuch and thus arbitrarily escalating their privileges.

Is it possible to restrict the kinds of policies a developer can create? For example, can I create a policy which specifies what a developer can do, and then require that any policies they then create are some subset of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had the same discussion in our office and we came to the conclusion that no you can't.  If you grant developers the ability to create and attach policies then there is no way to prevent them escalating their privileges.  The best solution we came up with is creating a bunch of Role and Policy templates and allowing developers to just attach those policies to the Role they create.

In the end we found it easier to trust our developers somewhat (and to upskill them through education) and do isolation/damage control by having accounts per team/product and by making use of cloud-trail and trusted advisor to monitor for abnormal usage.